# Bootstrap table td not abiding by my widths set

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a `vue` app using normal `Bootstrap 4` **NOT** `Vue-Bootstrap`. I have `responsive-table`s all over the site and all are working except one and I can't figure out why. I have even taken a fully working one and tried that and still, it does not listen to the `widths`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 8%">Item</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 3%">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">Brand</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-right" style="width: 4%">RRP</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-right" style="width: 4%">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 4%">Stock level</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">Weight (KG)</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 6%">EAN</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">MPN</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 31%">Web friendly name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="product in stock">
                        <td scope="row">{{product.item}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">
                            <span v-tooltip:bottom.html="product.description">{{product.description}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{product.class}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{product.retail_price | amountFormat}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{product.price_each | amountFormat}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.free_stock}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.weight}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">
                            <span v-tooltip:bottom.html="product.ean">{{product.ean}}</span>{{product.ean}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">
                            <span v-tooltip:bottom.html="product.mpn">{{product.mpn}}</span>{{product.mpn}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">
                            <span v-tooltip:bottom.html="product.web_name">{{product.web_name}}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gives the following with a horizontal scroll. Note notice i have the 'Description' column width less than the 'Item' width but it definantly is not 3%.
[image]

All my other table are set-up exactly this way and there is no different CSS being added in this page to 'break' it

Also if I use `devtools` to change the first `column` `width` to 2%, it also will not update it and no idea why

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, bootstrap caters for responsiveness automatically with tables and such. However in your image snip I'm not seeing your other columns, maybe if you added the rest of them it would fix itself? Since "description" is a rather decently long word I don't know if you can change its width just like that. You might need to change it's text size which in turn could allow you to change the column width. This is just me speculating though.

Comment: All columns are there. The screenshot is for the HTML I added. the 'Desc' col should be '3%'. There is a horizontal scrollbar displaying. all total widths equal 100%.

If using dev tools, I then change the first column to 2%, it doesn't update

Comment: Very confusing, not sure I can help out much. Perhaps try using "px" instead of %. Sometimes using px just does the trick for things. However you'll have to play around with the number if this works since px means pixels.